# Sum all values in dataframe which have the same time in seconds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, plot

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
   flow     seq     src             dest          time           size
0   0002      1  10.0.0.1/44225  10.0.0.4/8999  15:48:11.734242   100
1   0002      2  10.0.0.1/44225  10.0.0.4/8999  15:48:11.735910   100
2   0002      3  10.0.0.1/44225  10.0.0.4/8999  15:48:11.738209   100
3   0002      4  10.0.0.1/44225  10.0.0.4/8999  15:48:11.740504   100  
4   0002      5  10.0.0.1/44225  10.0.0.4/8999  15:48:11.741619   100
```

This dataframe represent udp packets sent from one src to a destination on a given time with a given packet size. What I want is to plot the dataframe in a way where I sum up all the size for one second. Meaning that I have in this example 15:48:11.734242 to 15:48:11.741619, I want to sum all packet size from the given second 15:48:11.

Note: There are thousands of lines in my dataframe and I want to plot the size of packets per second. Right now I only plot for each packet the size which will always give me a straight line like this: [image: my plot graph] but I want something like this:

[image: what I want to have]

Comment: What is `df.time.dtype`?

Comment: It is datetime64[ns]

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor). Try - `df.groupby(df.time.dt.seconds).sum()` or `df.groupby(df.time.dt.strftime('%S').sum()`

Comment: Or resample and aggregate.:[https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#aggregation)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resample and sum/aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling).:

```
>>> df
   flow  seq             src           dest                       time  size
0     2    1  10.0.0.1/44225  10.0.0.4/8999 2020-12-06 15:48:11.734242   100
1     2    2  10.0.0.1/44225  10.0.0.4/8999 2020-12-06 15:48:11.735910   100
2     2    3  10.0.0.1/44225  10.0.0.4/8999 2020-12-06 15:48:11.738209   100
3     2    4  10.0.0.1/44225  10.0.0.4/8999 2020-12-06 15:48:11.740504   100
4     2    5  10.0.0.1/44225  10.0.0.4/8999 2020-12-06 15:48:11.741619   100

>>> df = df.set_index(df.time)
>>> df['size']
time
2020-12-06 15:48:11.734242    100
2020-12-06 15:48:11.735910    100
2020-12-06 15:48:11.738209    100
2020-12-06 15:48:11.740504    100
2020-12-06 15:48:11.741619    100
Name: size, dtype: int64

>>> df['size'].resample('1S').sum()
time
2020-12-06 15:48:11    500
Freq: S, Name: size, dtype: int64
>>>
>>> df.resample('1S').agg({'size':sum})
                     size
time
2020-12-06 15:48:11   500
```

---

Groupby and sum using the dt accessor.

```
>>> df.groupby(df.time.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).sum()  
          flow  seq  size
time
15:48:11    10   15   500

>>> df.groupby(df.time.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).sum()['size']
time
15:48:11    300
15:48:12    180
Name: size, dtype: int64

>>> df.groupby(df.time.dt.second).sum('size')
      flow  seq  size
time
11      10   15   500
```

Comment: Thanks, How Can I plot the result from `df.groupby(df.time.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).sum()['size']`. I want to have as x values the time and and y values the sum of size.

Comment: @MohammedAbdu - [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html)